# The dimension of birkoff polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polyhedra

Let $P_m$ be a subset for R^mxm be the polytope given by:
$x_i,_j \ge 0$

$x_i,_1 + ... +  x_i,_m \le 1$

$x_1,_j + ... +  x_m,_j \le 1$

$\sum_{1 \le i,j \le m } \ x_i,_j \ge m-1$

Contruct a natural affine map $f$ from $P_n$ to the birkoff polytope B_n+1. Use $f$ to prove that the dimension of the birkoff polytope is

dim$B_n=(n-1)^2$

Comment: This sounds and looks like homework. Is it? If it is, might you tell us where you got the problem from and what have your tried?

Comment: I have tried close to everything, and i see the idea (I think), but i can't put it in to words.